# How to get origianl text id from View programatically in android?

Tags: android

In Android there is this method to get the `id` of a view:

```
int id = view.getId();
```

But this returns a dynamically generated integer value that has been assigned to the view at runtime.

I need to access the original string id. For example, for the following view, I want to get `@+id/likesCount`:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/likesCount"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How can I get that?

Comment: The most happy duplicate of my entire lifetime. I never knew that I had to search for resources. I was searching for string id in android and I could get no results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, the right approach to do it is using `tag`. You can give that id in `tag` and programmatically get it.

```
String id = view.getTag().toString()
```

Comment: Sir what about `getResources().getResourceEntryName( resid);`